# Why inherit OpenAI base gym class for a custom Environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

My question is pretty simple. Why at all do we need to inherit the base openAi env class while writing a custom environment? What advantage does it offer? I can as well write my own functions and make a working environment.